# What is the Difference between AndroidViewModel and ViewModel in Android Architecture Components?

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle, android-architecture-components

I have been working on Android Architecture Components for a while which was introduced in Google IO 2017

One of their Component to avoid configuration changes issue they provide `ViewModel` and `AndroidViewModel` classes

As per the doc:

**AndroidViewModel** : Application context aware `ViewModel`

**ViewModel** : ViewModels can also be used as a communication layer between different Fragments of an Activity.Each Fragment can acquire the `ViewModel` using the same key via their Activity

But for `AndoirdViewModel` scenario I can get application context by extending a class to Application class

What is the actual difference between them in Android Development? Because both are attached to Activity/Fragment life cycle only.

Comment: you are asking 2 things in same question, I believe you can switch the title and focus it about why use AndroidViewModel instead extending Application. The answer that @CommonsWare gave is still valid.
In that way you can ask to remove the "duplicated" tag because create a new question for a good answer... I don't think is a good idea.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> But for AndoirdViewModel scenario I can get application context by extending a class to Application class

Creating your own custom subclass of `Application` does not magically make that singleton instance available to a `ViewModel`.

It is possible to create a custom subclass of `Application` that has its own `getInstance()` method or something to expose the singleton directly. Google does not like this pattern (and neither do I, for that matter), and so Google does not steer developers towards using it.

> What is the actual difference between them in Android Development?

A `ViewModel` on its own has no good way to get a `Context`. `AndroidViewModel` supplies an `Application` for use as a `Context`, and specifically supplies the `Application` singleton so we are sure that the `Context` itself does not represent a memory leak.

Comment: Out of curiosity why doesn't Google (or you) like the subclass of Application with getInstance() ?

Comment: @neteinstein: I can't speak for Google. I'm not a fan as it makes using `Application` too easy, and many times `Application` is the wrong type of `Context` to use.